# Fade out subviews except one specific subview

Tags: ios, uiview, fadeout

I am trying to fade out whole view but one specific `subview`, which would emphasize the `subview` with the more clearer look. Let's say if self.view has 5 `textfields` and 2 `UIView` as `subviews` and I want 1 `UIView` to be emphasized. Is there a way to fade out/in the whole self.view with 5 `textfields` and 1 `UIView` without touching the emphasized `UIView`?

I have already tried to use method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

**such as:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.alpha = 0.5f;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;}];
```

But, it seemed like whole subviews are affected by the UIView animation above. Any advice or tip will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you lower the alpha of a `UIView`, all it's subview's alpha will be lowered. A solution to your problem would be to lower the alpha of each subview individually, except the one you want:

```
UIView emphasizedView = ...

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                 animations:^{
                     for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
                         if (view != emphasizedView) {
                             view.alpha = 0.5f;
                         } else {
                             view.alpha = 1;
                         }
                     }

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;}];
```